# How to mock localStorage.setIem and localStorage.removeItem in JEST

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

when i try to mock the localStorage of a react component in jest as below,

```
spyOn(window.localStorage,'removeItem');
window.localStorage.removeItem("key1");
window.localStorage.removeItem("key2");
expect(window.localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith("key1");
expect(window.localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith("key2");
```

and used the below code for localStorage mocking

```
let localStorageMock = (function() {
  var storage = {};

  return {
    setItem: function(key, value) {
      storage[key] = value || '';
    },
    getItem: function(key) {
      return storage[key] || null;
    },
    removeItem: function(key) {
      delete storage[key];
    },
    get length() {
      return Object.keys(storage).length;
    },
    key: function(i) {
      var keys = Object.keys(storage);
      return keys[i] || null;
    }
  };
})();
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: localStorageMock });
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I didn't get any error message, but the lines are not covered in unit testing.

Answer (score 4):

I've done this for session storage for store testing by adding a setup environment script file with the following in;

`Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', { value: {}, writable: true });`

The package.json file then looks like;

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "jest/jest-setupTestFrameworkScriptFile.js",
}
```

I'm not actually convinced you need this in the latest version of jest however I've used this setup since a much earlier version.

One thing when using this approach you need to be aware of is that it can persist data between tests so you'll want to add the following in the beforeEach;

```
sessionStorage = {};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i too add this setupEnvScriptFile in package.json, but still the localStorage lines in the React component is not covered in unit testing.

Comment: can anyone help me to resolve the above issue, I tried searching in other sites but i couldn't find any solution for it.

Comment: It's been changed since to: `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`

Answer (score 1):

I used this in my project's `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
  "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/app/mock/localStorageMock.js"]
}
```